# Error when trying to access a pixel value in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel

I just started learning c++ and OpenCV. I've tried to write a program that allows me to click on a pixel and print out the pixel value in BGR. So far, when I click, my program returns the coordinate of the clicked pixel but when I want to access the BGR-value my program crashes. I'm streaming video from my webcam as input and I don't get any errors when i compile.

I've been reading a lot of similar questions in here but I haven't found any solution.

My program crashes when I include the line:
"cv::Vec3f BGR = matOriginal.at(click[0][0],click[0][1]);"

The rest of my program is as follows:

```
int click[1][2];

void mouseEvent(int Event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
if(Event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
{
    printf("Valgt pixel: [%d,%d] \n ",x,y);
    click[0][0] = x;
    click[0][1] = y;
}
}

int main()
{
VideoCapture capWebcam(0);
if(capWebcam.isOpened() == false)
{
    printf("Error: capWebcam not accessed successfully \n");
    return(1);
}
Mat matOriginal;
char charCheckForEscKey=0;
while(charCheckForEscKey !=27)
{
    if(capWebcam.read(matOriginal) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Frame not read\n \n");
        break;
    }
    cv::imshow("Original",matOriginal);
    setMouseCallback("Original",mouseEvent,0);

    // Print BGR-value when mouseclick
    if(click[0][0]>0 && click[0][1]>0)
    {

    cv::Vec3f BGR = matOriginal.at<cv::Vec3f>(click[0][0],click[0][1]); // When this statement is included, I get an ERROR

    double B=BGR[0];    // B
    double G=BGR[1];    // G
    double R=BGR[2];    // R


    click[0][0] = 0; // Resetting the click-matrix
    click[0][1] = 0;
    }

    charCheckForEscKey = cv::waitKey(10);
}
return(0);
```

}

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Express

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It seems your `click` variable is not initialized (contains garbage). Try with `cv::Vec3f BGR = matOriginal.at<cv::Vec3f>(click[0][1],click[0][0]);`, and you should check if `click[0][0]` or `click[0][1]` are out of range before trying to access `matOriginal` elements.

Comment: I think you need to check for the type of matOriginal (print matOriginal.type()) to make sure it is indeed Vec3f and not Vec3b. This simple fact could possibly explain all your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, two different things could be going on here:

- The crash happens because `click` is **not initialized**:

When the execution of your program reaches the **while** loop, and the user has not pressed the mouse button, there's no way to tell what values are stored by `click` since they are most probably garbage from the memory.

This means that when you program first runs, `click` could be storing values larger than the dimensions of `matOriginal`, thus rendering you a crash for trying to access indexes that doesn't exist.

**Always initialize your variables!**

```
int main()
{
    click[0][0] = -1;
    click[0][1] = -1;
    // ...
}
```

What I just said could be tested by printing these values to the screen before accessing them:

```
std::cout << "X: " << click[0][0] << " Y: " << click[0][1] << std::endl;
cv::Vec3f BGR = matOriginal.at<cv::Vec3f>(click[0][0], click[0][1]);
```

- The crash happens because **`cv::Mat` is expecting the X,Y (row,column) values in the reverse order (column,row)**:

I think that's most likely the cause of the problem. Try:

```
cv::Vec3f BGR = matOriginal.at<cv::Vec3f>(click[0][1], click[0][0]);
```